# USB bar code scanner not working on Raspbian

Tags: linux, usb, devices, input, ascii

My USB bar code scanner (SYMBOL LS2208) is recognized as a HID.

```
hid-generic 0003:05E0:0600.000F: hiddev0,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Device [\xffffffef\xffffffbe\xffffffa9\xffffffbe\xffffffa9Symbol Technologies, Inc, 2002 Symbol Bar Code Scanner] on usb-bcm2708_usb-1.3/input0
```

When I scan bar codes it doesn't send ASCII chars.

(It 'beeps' and then text editor is left blank.)

I have tried re-configuring the scanner to do Simple COM port emulation. But after testing when it is configured this way - it doesn't even scan at all.

How can I get this scanner to send ASCII codes to my Raspberry Pi 2?

Comment: You want to configure it as a USB keyboard. If you scan the "USB Keyboard HID" code on p. 4 of the quick start guide, does it work then? You might have to unplug/replug it after scanning. Also, does it work when connected to a different machine?

Comment: The scanner worked on my windows machine before I configured it to Simple COM - but it did not work after I changed it to Simple Com Port Emulation.

When you say page 4 of the quick start guide - what do you mean? I have a manual here: http://www.spiritdatacapture.co.uk/manuals/motorola/Symbol%20LS2208%20Reference%20Guide.pdf

Comment: https://portal.motorolasolutions.com/Support/US-EN/Mobile+Networks+RFID+and+BarCode+Scanners/Bar+Code+Scanning/General+Purpose+Scanners/LS2208_US-EN has all the manuals. One of them is the quick start guide—actually two of them, depending on the revision you have. Both have a code to set it back to the USB HID keyboard mode. Looks to be p. 109 of the manual you're looking at.

Comment: Which one would it be on page 109?|
*HID Keyboard Emulation??
This did not work for me - I downloaded the driver on a microsoft machine first and then configured it and everything.

Comment: Yes, "HID Keyboard Emulation". It should scan that code if its powered up. Will probably beep, but won't actually output anything to the computer. Note that it may not scan from screen—you'll probably have to print out that page. If even that doesn't get it working again, p. 45 has the reset to defaults code. Get it working on the Windows box again, then worry about the Pi.

Comment: Okay - I configured it to "HID Keyboard Emulation" and then I connected it back to my pi - it beeps when scanning - but nothing is sent to my text editor. Do I have to write a code to anticipate the data and then write it?
I don't understand why nothing is showing up

Comment: It scan's on the windows machine - but not the raspb

Comment: Next to check is `dmesg` (see if the kernel is saying anything when you attach it—there is likely an explanation there). And (if you install `input-utils`) `lsinput` to see if its there. If so, `input-events` or `evtest` to check if the kernel is getting keys from it and ignoring for some reason. [Normally barcode scanners just work… all mine do, except when there is some weird kernel USB rule.]

Comment: lsusb: 
Bus 001 Device 022: ID 05e0:1200 Symbol Technologies Bar Code Scanner

Comment: I cant paste the entire dmesg because its too long

Comment: Just looking for anything added to dmesg when you plug in the barcode scanner. Also, is your editor running under X, on the console, or something else?

Comment: But this is what I think is important from dmesg:

[16062.480743] hid-generic 0003:05E0:1200.0012: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [\xffffffef\xffffffbe\xffffffa9\xffffffbe\xffffffa9Symbol Technologies, Inc, 2002 Symbol Bar Code Scanner] on usb-bcm2708_usb-1.3/input0

Comment: The text editor is at this location:

/usr/share/raspi-ui-overrides/applications

File name: leadpad.desktop

Comment: How can i download `input-utils`?

Comment: does `apt-get install input-utils` work? Also, have you tried restarting X with the scanner plugged in? And since this appears to be X, `xinput` is another command to check.

Comment: `pi@raspberrypi ~ $ input-events
usage: input-events [ -g ] [ -t <sec> ] devnr`

Comment: `sudo lsinput` will tell you all the devices connected, along with the `devnr` (device number) to pass to `input-events`. BTW: might need `sudo input-events «devnr»`.